# Add a new class to a draggable clone and not to the original element

Tags: javascript, jquery, frontend, drag, droppable

I have a list of elements that are draggable and when I drag one of the elements I want it to:

1. Clone the element on drag start
2. Add new class to new cloned element on drop

Problem: When I drop the new clone element, the class is applied to all draggable elements.

How do I apply the class only to the new cloned element.

Here is the code I am working with:

```js
$('.draggable-item').draggable({
    appendTo: '.drop-container',
    helper: 'clone',
    start: function (event, ui) {
        $(this).show();
    },
    stop: function (event, ui) {
        $(this).show()
        // .addClass( "drag-active")
        .draggable(".draggable-item");

    }
  });

 $('.runway-items-container').droppable({
    accept: '.draggable-item',
    drop: function (event, ui) {
        $('.draggable-item').draggable()
        $( this )       
          .offset();

    }
  });

$('.runway .drag-active').draggable({
    helper: 'clone',
    start: function (event, ui) {
        $(this).hide();
    },
    stop: function (event, ui) {
        $(this).show();

    }
  });
```

Comment: do you need to apply the class to the item once it's dropped, or just to the clone helper?